# android how to tweet to specific user?

Tags: android, twitter

I am making tweet button to send defined message to predefined user.

this code only sends tweet to my wall
how to set reciever when i tweet?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setComponent(targetComponent);
        String intentType = (targetComponent.getClassName().contains("com.twidroid")) ? 
            "application/twitter" : "text/plain";
        intent.setType(intentType);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "@victim  Spacemarine has voted for the sake of Emperor! #becounted");
        this.startActivity(intent);
```

my result
[image]

but it goes to my wall not to victim's as i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user follows you, you will be able to send him a Direct Message. Otherwise the only solution you have is the one that you use in your question.

Comment: do not use twit so i did not know that, it made me lot of stress:) thanks